# "document.createElement" Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, createelement

I wanted to create numerous rows in a popup to show my data using for loop, I was using text string to create and append the div , However I found `document.createElement` is performant and used that which increased the performance 20%, but since I populate 1000s of rows the time taken to create element by `document.createElement` is very high. Is there any way to improve performance by creating element once and resuse it with numerous instance, any advice on this would be appreciated

Comment: It's important that you don't trigger document reflows: http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/

Comment: Did you try documentFragment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you have created an element, you can use `Element.cloneNode()` to copy it. It takes same time as `document.createElement()`, but has one advantage: if you have set several attributes or childNodes/innerHTML on the element, you can copy those too with one call: `Element.cloneNode(true)`.

Most time takes the DOM-insertion of newly created Elements, and therefor insertion of every single new element is slow. A faster way is to create a [`documentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), append all new elements to that in the structure you need and then add the complete fragment to the DOM.

Comment: Here's an article showing performance comparison results between jQuery, string & `documentFragment`: https://howchoo.com/g/mmu0nguznjg/learn-the-slow-and-fast-way-to-append-elements-to-the-dom