# Better way to optimize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am relatively new at coding, but this is my etch-a-sketch project. This works to take a user's given grid size, but it is very slow and crashed the page once the size is over 40. It loops through the array every time just to update the height and width and I don't know if I could make this process any faster. Any help would be great!

```
const body = document.body;
const bodyDiv = document.createElement('div');
bodyDiv.setAttribute('id', 'boxContainer');

body.append(bodyDiv);

const btnDiv = document.createElement('div');
btnDiv.setAttribute('id', 'btnDiv');

bodyDiv.append(btnDiv);

const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.setAttribute('id', 'changeGridSizeBtn');
btn.innerText = 'Click to change grid size!'

btnDiv.append(btn);

const gridContainer = document.createElement('div')
gridContainer.setAttribute('id', 'gridContainer')

bodyDiv.append(gridContainer);


for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    const boxDiv = document.createElement('div');
    boxDiv.className = "box";
    gridContainer.append(boxDiv);
}

let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) =>{
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    });
});

function randomColor(){
   let randomColorGenerator =  Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
   let randomColor = '#' + randomColorGenerator;
   return randomColor;
}

const btnHover = document.getElementById('btnDiv');
btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) =>{
    btnHover.style.boxShadow = '5px 10px #888888';
})
const btnUnHover = document.getElementById('btnDiv');

btn.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) =>{
    btnUnHover.style.removeProperty('box-shadow');
})

btn.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

    boxes.forEach(box =>{
        box.remove();
    })

    //This gets the user inputted grid size
    let finalUserGridSize = 0;
    function getUserGrid(){
        let userGridSize = prompt('Please enter a number between 1-100 for the grid size.');
        if (userGridSize < 0 || userGridSize > 100){
            getUserGrid();
        }
        else{
            return finalUserGridSize = userGridSize;
        }
    }

    getUserGrid(finalUserGridSize);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < finalUserGridSize * finalUserGridSize; i++){
        const boxDiv = document.createElement('div');
        boxDiv.className = "box";

        let boxWitdh = Math.round(960/finalUserGridSize) - 2;
        let boxHeight = Math.round(720/finalUserGridSize) - 2;
        
        function changeGridHeightWidth(){    
            let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
            let elementLegnth = elements.length;
            for (let x = 0; x < elementLegnth; x++) {
                elements[x].style.width=(boxWitdh+"px");
                elements[x].style.height=(boxHeight+'px');
            }
        }
        gridContainer.append(boxDiv);
        changeGridHeightWidth();
        let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
        boxes.forEach((box) => {
            box.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) =>{
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034314/document-createelement-performance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `document.createElement()` you could try to use `document.createDocumentFragment()` and append the element to DOM only once. See [this MDN article for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).